# C# deserialize xml (which include backslash) to an object through filestream

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, backslash

Maybe it is hard to describe the problem I meet in the title. Here is the example:

I have a xml file, and there is a string inside:

```
<List>
  <String>C\\blabla</String>
</List>
```

The object in C# is "list" for example.

And in my C# code:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(list));
Stream fs = new FileStream("here is the xml file location", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
list temp = (list)xs.Deserialize(fs);
```

But when I ues the string in the object, the value is:

```
temp.string = "C\\\\blabla";
```

The backslash has been doubled, the correct string should be

```
C\\blabla
```

Do anyone know what is the problem and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The string literal `"C\\\\blabla"` *is* the string `C\\blabla`. So if the string that you want is `C\\blabla`, and the string literal that you're seeing is `"C\\\\blabla"`, then that's already correct.

Comment: Silly question, but are you certain it's actually added the extra backslashes? If you're looking at the debug value of the string, it will look like `"C\\\\blabla"`. Have you tried outputting the string to the Output Window with `Trace.WriteLine` or some equivalent?

Comment: You could read C\\\\blabla as C [Delimit] \ [Delimit]\ blabla

Comment: When in doubt use : `temp.string = @"C\\blabla";`

Comment: Thanks, but what I need here is the string should be exactly the same with the format in XML file, it means I need the temp.string = "C\\blabla" istead of "C\\\\blabla", cause the value will be used in any other code.

Comment: @PaulSwetz I see, but how to exclude the [Delimit] during the string, cause the string will be used in other methods, I need to keep the right format. Thanks!